# I need help with my pathfinding algorithm

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, c

I am a student that is learning how to program and I started to develop my first platform game using C. However, I’m struggling with the pathfinding algorithm for the enemies.

My levels are basically a 30x45 array with numbers that have a 1 where there is a block, 2 ladders and 0 an empty space. I don’t know which path finding algorithm to use, mainly, because I have no idea how to create the graph.

Being a grid-based level, using an adjacency list or matrix, I guess that it would be quite complex if I had every walkable cell as a node.
I was thinking of using BFS or Dijkstra’s, but I don’t even know where to start.
I already know how the algorithms work, but I can’t figure out how to implement any of those.

I would appreciate if anyone could help me.

Comment: Where specifically did you run into trouble implementing A* for this case? What you describe is one of the most common use cases for it, so it's not immediately clear what help you might need from us that hasn't been written up in dozens of existing tutorials about the algorithm. What have you done so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I adapt A\* pathfinding to work with platformers?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/118912/how-can-i-adapt-a-pathfinding-to-work-with-platformers) - you may also be interested in [How can I implement platformer pathfinding?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/73608/10408), [Can I jump from A to B?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/69926/10408) and [Making AI jump on a spot effectively](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/37916/10408).